# Return types that cannot be overloaded in C#

Tags: c#

Why is it not possible to overload functions with return types like Ienumerator?

Is this type treated differently than other types that allow for function overloading?

Comment: Because C# decided it would not support return type overloading. This is consistent for every type, although there is some ambiguity sometimes when the spec talks about method signature (on a C# or CLR level). But bottom line: no, return types are not part of the method signature which is used to determine overloads.

Comment: It's not like `IEnumerator` is magic, it's just that you cannot overload functions just by return type.

Comment: Just one example, if allowed it'll break here `var returnValue = SOmeMethodWithReturnTypeOverloads()` ..!! (This is not the only reason though)

Comment: C# does not allow it but it's possible in general. Haskell for example has it.

Answer (score 1):

Return types are not taken into consideration when resolving overloaded methods. There is nothing special in `IEnumerator`. It's the same for the whole type system. If you want to return different types from one method, you need to declare a base class or interface and return an instance of that type. Afterwards, you can check what's the actual type of the object, cast it and perform specific actions.

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public class Bar : IFoo
{
    public void BarMethod() {}
}

public class Biz : IFoo
{
    public void BizMethod() {}
}
```

Somewhere else you might declare such a method:

```
public class C
{
    public IFoo M(int i)
    {
        return (i == 0) ? new Bar() : new Biz();
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
C c = new C();
var foo = c.M(1);
var barFoo = foo as Bar;
if (barFoo != null)
{
    barFoo.BarMethod();
}
else
{
    var bizFoo = foo as Biz;
    if (bizFoo != null)
    {
        bizFoo.BizMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple example of why it wouldn't make sense.

```
var class Demo
{
    public int GetValue()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    public string GetValue()
    {
        return "3";
    }
}
```

and the usage

```
void Main(){
  var demo = new Demo();
  var thing = demo.GetValue();
}
```

The compiler would have no idea which GetValue() you wanted.

and even if you said its type like

```
void Main(){
  var demo = new Demo();
  string thing = demo.GetValue();
}
```

It would not be good coding practice, and would make your use of "var" invalid.
Implying a method with the same name can return two different types mean the intention of the code is not clear.

i.e. in one instance its "this" and another its "that".

Comment: There are plenty of things possible in the language today that in some circumstances produce a compiler error about ambiguity. The C# developers just decided they did not want the return type to be part of the signature when working out eligible method candidates. If they had decided otherwise, using `var` would simply be ambiguous, but `int thing = demo.GetValue();` wouldn't be. Also remember that `var` came later, when they first decided, `var` did not exist.

Comment: My example was super simple. Lets say you did 'ProcessWork(demo.GetValue())' now what? there is good reason they did not make it part of the signature, the compiler can make suggestion and informed decision as there is no ambiguity in its intent.

Comment: Honestly is like people don't bother to read.. why is this down marked?

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question? `var` was added a long time after the decision was made, and back then there was no ambiguity because you had to specify the variable type to put the value into. The compiler *could* have deduced it back then. This was a decision, not a technical limitation. There are plenty of things that are legal in the current language that *does* lead to ambiguity, they just decided they didn't want this particular feature.

Comment: what part of "why it wouldn't make sense." and an example, does not answer the question.... **ultimately the c# developers decided this**... and that's that, but usually its helpful to give context as to why they may have made this decision... just my 2c

Comment: Yes, but again, the example using `var` is invalid because at the time they made that decision, `var` did not exist. If the question had been "Why is it not a good idea to change C# to include the return type in the signature", this would've been different. The question is "Why is this not legal". Things we have/know now doesn't really count because "why" is "because" and "because" was decided in C# 1.0.

Comment: This give context as to why they still don't support it..., only using the past and means of measure doesn't give context to why it is still not supported. I get your point but... I personally think explain why it wouldn't make sense and giving an example is more beneficial than saying "cozs the devs decided so and refuse to change it for no reason" I believe var and ambiguity are majar reasons it,is the why it is, and hasn't changed. The c# develeoper could change it.... "why haven't they...." and that's why its not supported.